# Jenkins git timeout killing process

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running a Jenkins pipeline to fetch/clone code from an repo using the following:

```
git branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'jenkins_ssh_key', url: 'git@github.com:myrepo/myrepo.git'
```

Due to the size of the repo, the process gets killed after 10 minutes as the git plugin has a 10 minute timeout.

Is there a way of increasing the size of the git plugin timeout within a Jenkins Pipeline?

Note: I have seen you can increase the timeout in a freestyle project, but how is this accomplished in a pipeline?

Comment: Yes you can chose your timeout under the Additional Behavior

Comment: I can see this in a free style project, but not in a pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Use the long form of the checkout plugin. For example, I set the checkout and clone timeout values to 60 mins.

```
def checkout_scm() {
    checkout(
        scm: [$class                           : 'GitSCM',
              branches                         : [[name: 'maser']],
              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'],
                                                                    [$class: 'CheckoutOption', timeout: 60],
                                                                    [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: true, reference: '', shallow: true, timeout: 60]],
              submoduleCfg                     : [],
              userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: 'jenkins-ssh-creds', url: 'git@company.org:project/some_repo.git']]]
            )
}

node('linux') {
    stage('Checkout') {
        checkout_scm()
    }
}
```